# Iterate li in html with vba

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I cant seem to locate an answer to this anywhere through searches...

I am trying to iterate through a list on a webpage using vba and then use the data in excel.

Accessing the webpage is fine, locating the correct div is fine but I cannot find how to iterate through the list.

What I am trying is:

```
Sub getdata()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer 
Dim html As HTMLDocument 
Set ie = New InternetExplorer 
ie.Visible = False 
ie.navigate "http://www.springfieldeducationalfurniture.co.uk/products/60-Chair-Trolley/11116/"

Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Attempting connection ..."
DoEvents Loop

Set html = ie.document 
Set ie = Nothing 
Application.StatusBar = ""

Dim content Set content = html.getElementsByClassName("tabs__content")

For Each bullet In content
    'tried this
    IHtml = bullet.innerHTML'this gives the whole div not sure how to convert to a string
    'and this but get "Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method"
    IHtml = bullet.getElementsByTagName("li")

Next

End Sub
```

They HTML I am after is as follows, I am wanting to iterate through the `<ul>` in the `<div class="tabs__content">` and assign the content i.e. "Requires simple self assembly" to a cell in excel (once I read the data from the list, the rest is easy):

```
    <div class="tabs">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="tabs__nav">
                <li class="is-active background-grey-lighter">
                    <a href="#">Description</a>
                </li>
                                                <li class="background-grey-light">
                    <a href="#">Delivery</a>
                </li>



            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="tabs__tab tabs__tab--product-info is-active">

            <div class="tabs__title">
                <a href="#">Information</a>
            </div>

            <div class="tabs__content">
                <div class="container">
                    <p>
    60 Chair Trolley</p>
<ul>
    <li>
        Requires simple self assembly</li>
    <li>
        Non marking wheels&nbsp;</li>
    <li>
        Heavy duty lockable castors</li>
    <li>
        Black frame</li>
    <li>
        Vertical / hanging chair storage</li>
    <li>
        Does not fit through a single doorway</li>
    <li>
        Fits through double doors when fully loaded</li>
    <li>
        Dimensions: W780 x L1770 x H1340mm</li>
</ul>
<p>
    Code: Y16527<br />
    &nbsp;</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>



        <div class="tabs__tab tabs__tab--product-info ">

            <div class="tabs__title">
                <a href="#">Delivery</a>
            </div>

            <div class="tabs__content">
                <div class="container">

                    <p>
    Please <a href="/contact"><span style="color: rgb(0, 0, 255);">contact us</span></a> for delivery information.</p>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
```

Comment: `Set ie = Nothing` - why do you need this? Would it work if you remove it?

Comment: iterate through and produce what?

Comment: @Vityata thanks but no that makes no difference, I have `Set html = ie.document` before that (tried it anyway just to check :))

Comment: @QHarr i just need to be able to read it, assign it to a variable and ultimately into a cell on excel, the latter part is easy if I can sus out how to iterate through that one list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

And this targets the class you mentioned. Requires reference to HTML Object library and Microsoft XML (your version)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Getinfo2()

    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument

    With http
        .Open "GET", "http://www.springfieldeducationalfurniture.co.uk/products/60-Chair-Trolley/11116/", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim posts As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim post As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Set posts = html.getElementsByClassName("tabs__content")(0).getElementsByTagName("li")

    For Each post In posts
        Debug.Print post.innerHTML
    Next post

End Sub
```

Output:

[image: Output]

This gets the html for all the li elements

```
Option Explicit

Sub Getinfo2()

    Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument

    With http
        .Open "GET", "http://www.springfieldeducationalfurniture.co.uk/products/60-Chair-Trolley/11116/", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim posts As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim post As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    Set posts = html.getElementsByTagName("li")

    For Each post In posts
        Debug.Print post.innerHTML
    Next post

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative option that doesn't require any reference's to library's (Late binding). It also show a different way of looping through the class, as well as the LI's.

```
Sub getData()

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim li As Object
    Dim tabsClass As Object

    'Late Binding
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    On Error GoTo Catch
    ie.Visible = False
    ie.navigate "http://www.springfieldeducationalfurniture.co.uk/products/60-Chair-Trolley/11116/"

    While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend

    'LOOP EACH CLASS ELEMENT
    For Each tabsClass In ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("tabs__content")

        'LOOP EACH LI WITHIN THAT CLASS
        For Each li In tabsClass.getElementsByTagName("li")
            Debug.Print li.innertext
        Next li

    Next tabsClass

    'CLOSE INSTANCE OF IE
Catch:
    ie.Quit
    Set ie = Nothing

End Sub
```